# Parsing Json file in python to return specific values

Tags: python, json

I am new to coding, and am having trouble assigning values from a JSON file to python variables, whatever I try, I still get the same 'keyerror'. My end goal is to return a specific value from an API call. For example, how would I return the 'list_price' variable from the following JSON converted API call in Python?  Thank you

```
print(response.json())
```

```
    {'status': 200,
 'data': {'total': 1597,
  'count': 2,
  'results': [{'primary_photo': {'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/929602ed79a23cf883255a44b3990541l-m1501343370s-w1024_h768.jpg'},
    'last_update_date': '2021-02-06T03:05:00Z',
    'source': {'plan_id': None,
     'agents': [{'office_name': None}],
     'spec_id': None,
     'type': 'mls'},
    'tags': ['central_air', 'central_heat', 'community_elevator', 'basement'],
    'permalink': '88-Kingston-St-32_Boston_MA_02111_M90414-80357',
    'status': 'for_sale',
    'list_date': '2021-02-02T22:55:34Z',
    'open_houses': None,
    'description': {'baths_3qtr': None,
     'year_built': 2005,
     'sold_price': None,
     'baths_full': None,
     'name': None,
     'baths_half': None,
     'lot_sqft': None,
     'sqft': None,
     'baths': None,
     'sub_type': 'condo',
     'baths_1qtr': None,
     'garage': None,
     'stories': None,
     'beds': 0,
     'type': 'condos'},
    'branding': [{'name': '360 Realty LLC', 'photo': None, 'type': 'Office'}],
    'list_price': 30000,
    'lead_attributes': {'show_contact_an_agent': True},
    'property_id': '9041480357',
    'photos': [{'tags': [{'label': 'floor_plan',
        'probability': 0.99355512857437},
       {'label': 'unknown', 'probability': 0.0064440788701177},
       {'label': 'bathroom', 'probability': 5.3076382755535e-07}],
      'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/929602ed79a23cf883255a44b3990541l-m1501343370s-w1024_h768.jpg'}],
    'flags': {'is_new_construction': None,
     'is_for_rent': None,
     'is_subdivision': None,
     'is_contingent': None,
     'is_price_reduced': None,
     'is_pending': None,
     'is_foreclosure': None,
     'is_plan': None,
     'is_coming_soon': None,
     'is_new_listing': False},
    'community': None,
    'products': {'brand_name': 'basic_opt_in'},
    'virtual_tours': None,
    'other_listings': {'rdc': [{'listing_id': '2925666283',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'for_sale',
       'primary': True}]},
    'listing_id': '2925666283',
    'price_reduced_amount': None,
    'location': {'address': {'postal_code': '02111',
      'state': 'Massachusetts',
      'coordinate': {'lon': -71.059097, 'lat': 42.352626},
      'city': 'Boston',
      'state_code': 'MA',
      'line': '88 Kingston St Unit SL32'},
     'street_view_url': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?channel=rdc-streetview&client=gme-movesalesinc&location=88%20Kingston%20St%20Unit%20SL32%2C%20Boston%2C%20MA%2002111&size=640x480&source=outdoor&signature=ihDr2a39PC44-Okw5NPFU4JjKIU=',
     'county': {'fips_code': '25025', 'name': 'Suffolk'}},
    'matterport': False},
   {'primary_photo': {'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/4d6c6c5c8743a1a704068a588ddce7dfl-m510363797s-w1024_h768.jpg'},
    'last_update_date': '2021-01-25T03:05:00Z',
    'source': {'plan_id': None,
     'agents': [{'office_name': None}],
     'spec_id': None,
     'type': 'mls'},
    'tags': ['community_park',
     'community_security_features',
     'recreation_facilities',
     'garage_1_or_more',
     'medicalcare'],
    'permalink': '170-Tremont-St_Boston_MA_02111_M30957-14351',
    'status': 'for_sale',
    'list_date': '2021-01-21T23:11:44Z',
    'open_houses': None,
    'description': {'baths_3qtr': None,
     'year_built': 1989,
     'sold_price': None,
     'baths_full': None,
     'name': None,
     'baths_half': None,
     'lot_sqft': 2613600,
     'sqft': None,
     'baths': None,
     'sub_type': 'condo',
     'baths_1qtr': None,
     'garage': 1,
     'stories': None,
     'beds': 0,
     'type': 'condos'},
    'branding': [{'name': 'COMPASS', 'photo': None, 'type': 'Office'}],
    'list_price': 60000,
    'lead_attributes': {'show_contact_an_agent': True},
    'property_id': '3095714351',
    'photos': [{'tags': [{'label': 'unknown', 'probability': 0.99945098161697},
       {'label': 'floor_plan', 'probability': 0.00054820330115035},
       {'label': 'farm_land', 'probability': 5.6766640454953e-07}],
      'href': 'https://ap.rdcpix.com/4d6c6c5c8743a1a704068a588ddce7dfl-m510363797s-w1024_h768.jpg'}],
    'flags': {'is_new_construction': None,
     'is_for_rent': None,
     'is_subdivision': None,
     'is_contingent': None,
     'is_price_reduced': None,
     'is_pending': None,
     'is_foreclosure': None,
     'is_plan': None,
     'is_coming_soon': None,
     'is_new_listing': False},
    'community': None,
    'products': {'brand_name': 'essentials'},
    'virtual_tours': None,
    'other_listings': {'rdc': [{'listing_id': '2925285253',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'for_sale',
       'primary': True},
      {'listing_id': '2925285254',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'for_rent',
       'primary': True},
      {'listing_id': '609668737',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'for_rent',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '2921354275',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '609826957',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '2917898326',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '2917902143',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '615481969',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '615205757',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '614988797',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '614755513',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '614794829',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '607452909',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '596470441',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '581664473',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '565451533',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '563974705',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '551890401',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '546253669',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '514743401',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None},
      {'listing_id': '509643985',
       'listing_key': None,
       'status': 'off_market',
       'primary': None}]},
    'listing_id': '2925285253',
    'price_reduced_amount': None,
    'location': {'address': {'postal_code': '02111',
      'state': 'Massachusetts',
      'coordinate': {'lon': -71.058739, 'lat': 42.350376},
      'city': 'Boston',
      'state_code': 'MA',
      'line': '170 Tremont St Unit Park'},
     'street_view_url': 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?channel=rdc-streetview&client=gme-movesalesinc&location=170%20Tremont%20St%20Unit%20Park%2C%20Boston%2C%20MA%2002111&size=640x480&source=outdoor&signature=B0bK7pc9tIUp3HjklL43DTTXkCs=',
     'county': {'fips_code': '25025', 'name': 'Suffolk'}},
    'matterport': False}]}}
```

Comment: There is no "listing_price" element here.  There are two "list_price" elements, at `json["data"]["results"][0]["list_price"]` and `json["data"]["results"][1]["list_price"]`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is a community willing to help, but you need to show some effort in solving the issue you have. So far, the only thing you shown is the data that you receive, but no code that would do what you want to do. Also, please check this link in order to help you write high quality questions, that would lead to more high-quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Best regard,

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it must be 'list_price' instead of  'listing_price', based on JSON.

You could access the node as follows, change the test.json for your API response:

```py
import json

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for p in data["data"]["results"]:
        print(p["list_price"])
```

Result:

```py
 python readJson.py
30000
60000
```